# determine the city from gps coordinates

Tags: python, data-analysis

I'm trying to find the city using the gps coordinates
my dataframe looks like that

```
        tripId  latitude    longitude
    0   1828765 50.126219   8.767003
    1   1828765 50.126173   8.766984
    ... ... ... ...
    497 1828714 53.680520   10.428270
    498 1828714 53.680497   10.428355
    499 1828714 53.680484   10.428431
```

i tried this code :

```
 import numpy as np
    df['location']=np.nan
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
    for i in range(df.shape[0]): 
        df['location'][i] =  geolocator.reverse(str(df['latitude'][i])+","+str(df['longitude'][i]))
```

but it doesn't work! **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'address', 'point', and 'raw'
does any of you have any idea how to solve this ?
Thank you

Comment: "It doesn't work". Explain what exactly happens

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov : UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Comment: i added str() for longitude and latitude , so now i have another error :
__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'address', 'point', and 'raw'

Comment: [Documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.ArcGIS.reverse) says that you can pass a tuple `(df['latitude'][i], df['longitude'][i])`, not necessarily a string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code, i hope that helps you:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import numpy as np

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='your_app_name')

coordinates = np.array([
    [50.126219,8.767003],
    [50.126173,8.766984],
    [53.680520,10.428270],
    [53.680497,10.428355],
    [53.680484,10.428431]
])

addresses = []

for coordinate in coordinates:
    addresses.append(geolocator.reverse(coordinate).address)

print(addresses)

# output:
['20, Willmannstraße, Fechenheim, Ost, Frankfurt am Main, Hessen, 60386, Deutschland',
 '20, Willmannstraße, Fechenheim, Ost, Frankfurt am Main, Hessen, 60386, Deutschland',
 'Pöhlen, Schönberg, Sandesneben-Nusse, Herzogtum Lauenburg, Schleswig-Holstein, 22929, Deutschland',
 'Pöhlen, Schönberg, Sandesneben-Nusse, Herzogtum Lauenburg, Schleswig-Holstein, 22929, Deutschland',
 'Pöhlen, Schönberg, Sandesneben-Nusse, Herzogtum Lauenburg, Schleswig-Holstein, 22929, Deutschland']
```

Your only mistake was that you were trying to make a formated print, when you just needed to pass the two coordinates.

I made that code save only the address but if you want more details you can go in the loop and exclude the .address method.

I hope that i did help you. Good Luck, man.